# jQuery regex/delete certain words from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Given the URL: `http://domain.com/view/2/permalink:14871638741230`

What is the best method, using jQuery/Javascript to delete the "permalink:xxxxx" from the URL, obviously bearing in mind that the number with the permalink will change from URL to URL...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about a regexp?

```
url = url.replace(/permalink:[a-zA-Z0-9]+/g, "");
```

It will replace `permalink:<one or more lowercase/uppercase letters and numbers>` with an empty string, i.e. removing it.

Comment: can this delete the numbers/letters after "permalink:" aswell?

Comment: @benhowdle89: It does, doesn't it?

Comment: @benhowdle89: Sorry, I thought they would always be digits.

Comment: @pimvdb he should have been clearer in his question: he specifically states '... that the **number** with the permalink ...'. Either way, you could also use url = url.replace(/permalink:[a-z0-9]/gi,''), this saves the visitor some bytes :)

Comment: Ok Tom, chill, I've aplogised!

Comment: @Tom Knapen: Thanks, the `i` flag would work great, but then again it would also accept `PERMALINK:` stuff, which is not 100% correct.

Comment: @pimvdb You're absolutely correct! I suggest Ben to stick with your proposal then.